# r auto arima excluding (0,0,0)

Tags: r, time-series, modeling

For the auto.arima function in forecast package of R, is there a way to let the function omit a model of arima(0,0,0), as I simply assume there must be some correlation within the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try looking at the help for the function
`auto.arima()`. Check the arguments `start.p`, `start.q`,
`d`,`max.d`